# Jmeter remote distributed testing on 3 slaves. How to interpret total TPS at end of run?

Tags: jmeter

I am Running a master and  3x Slave configuration of test servers;
How do you calculate total TPS at end of a test ?

is the TPS value the total TPS  of the three servers ?
or do i have to multiply it by three ?

Thanks 
G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the values that you see are consolidated ones and are from all 3 load generators (slaves).

In case you would require data from each slave, then enable/add a listener and write data to file

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you M Navneet Krishna